# PyQt5 - window over modal dialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have modal dialog over main application. In this dialog box, there is a button by clicking on which the widget appears. I need to show this widget in front of the modal window. Is there a way to accomplish this without making my modal dialog non-modal?

Comment: You can create next dialog with this widget.

Comment: Change the widget to be another modal dialog.

Comment: Grzegorz Bokota, ekhumoro, you are right. It really helped! thank you very much for your answers!